# jquery ui autocomplete does't close options menu if there is no focus when ajax returns

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jquery ui autocomplete widget with ajax, and on noticed the following problem.

Background: In order for the user to be able to focus on the autocomplete and get the options without typing anything, I use the focus event:

`autoComp.focus(function() { $(this).autocomplete("search", "");}`

However this produces the following effect: when the user clicks, an ajax request is being sent. While waiting for the response, the user then clicks elsewhere and the autocomplete is blurred. But as soon as the response returns, the options menu pops out, even though the autocomplete has no focus. In order to make it go away the user has to click once inside, and again outside the autocomplete, which is a bit annoying.

any ideas how I prevent this?

EDIT: I solved this in a very ugly way by building another mediator function that knows the element's ID, and this function calls the ajax function with the ID, which on success check the focus of the element, and returns null if it's not focused. It's pretty ugly and I'm still looking for alternatives.

EDIT#2: Tried to do as Wlliam suggested, still doesn't work.. the xhr is undefined when blurring. Some kind of a problem with the `this` keyword, maybe it has different meanings if I write the getTags function outside of the autocomplete?

```
this.autocomplete = $('.tab#'+this.id+' #tags').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: getTags,
    select: function(e, obj) {
        tab_id = $(this).parents('.tab').attr('id');
        tabs[tab_id].addTag(obj.item.label, obj.item.id, false);
        $(this).blur(); // This is done so that the options menu won't pop up again.
        return false;  // This is done so that the value will not stay in the input box after selection.
    },
    open: function() {},
    close: function() {}
});
$('.tab#'+this.id+' #tags').focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
$('.tab#'+this.id+' #tags').blur(function() {
    console.log('blurring');
    var xhr = $(this).data('xhr'); // This comes out undefined... :(
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.abort();
    };
    $(this).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
});
```

and this is the getTags function copied to the source keyword:

```
        function getTags(request, response)
        {
            console.log('Getting tags.');
            $(this).data('xhr', $.ajax({
                url: '/rpc',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'GetLabels',
                    arg0: JSON.stringify(request.term)
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Tags arrived:');
                    tags = [];
                    for (i in data) {
                        a = {}
                        a.id = data[i]['key'];
                        a.label = data[i]['name'];
                        tags.push(a);
                    }
                    response(tags);
                }
            }));
            console.log($(this).data('xhr'));
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use the callback option for the [`source`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source), in order to abort the AJAX request. Quoting from the overview of the autocomplete widget:

> The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single property called "term", which
>     refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the
>     user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will
>     equal "new yo".
> - A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain
>     the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on
>     the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above
>     for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with
>     label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom
>     source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always
>     call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This
>     ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

In your case, it'll probably look something like the following:

```
$("#autoComp").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var searchString = request.term;

        // ajax call to remote server, perhaps filtered with searchString
        $(this).data('xhr', $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                ...
                // pass back the data filtered by searchString
                response(filteredList);
            }
        }));
    },
    minLength: 0,
    focus: function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    }
})
// cancel the request when user click away from the input box
.blur(function() {
    var xhr = $(this).data('xhr');
    if (xhr) xhr.abort();
});
```

Comment: I had no idea that jquery objects can store associated data, so that's a good idea. However, I have a loading animation going on by the autocomplete loading class. If I do things your way, I have to remove the class myself right? Is that problematic?

Comment: What do you mean by "a loading animation going on by the autocomplete loading class"? Using a callback as source only gives you more flexibility, so I don't think it would hinder you providing animation. Could you update your answer with some code?

Comment: autocomplete adds automatically the "ui-autocomplete-loading" class (for the duration of the loading) that can be used for adding indication that it is loading. It removes this automatically once the ajax returned. If you abort it I'm assuming you have to remove it with another line of code, right?

Comment: Did as you suggested, but my xhr under the blur function always comes out undefined. Some kind of an issue with referencing to the owner of the function, my getTags function doesn't store the data where it should (can't seem to have access to the jquery element when inside the getTags function). See my latest edit for code.

Comment: BTW - in your code the callback response function is used outside of the ajax, and it should be inside I think.

Comment: Re. 1st comment: yes. Re. 2nd: It's most likely because that the `this` in two location refer to different object. Try to inspect the two `this`, and also try to use the explicit ID in your selector instead of using `this`. Re. 3rd: yes, you're correct.

Comment: So this doesn't really solve the problem, as I would still have to write the same function again for every instance of an autocomplete...  Isn't it weird that this behaves differently? I thought that on JS when you give functions as parameters this just copies them...
(anyway I +1'd for the effort)

Comment: You can achieve what you want: reusing the function. You just need to make sure you refer to the same object when binding the data. Is `this` in `getTag` gives you the same object as `this` in the `blur` handler?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3332/discussion-between-william-niu-and-uri)

Answer (score 1):

I got around this issue by using the [Open event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-open).  If the input doesn't have focus when the drop-down opens, I simply close it.

```
$("#autoComp").autocomplete({
  open: function() {
    if ($(this).is(':not(:focus)')) {
      $(this).autocomplete('close');
    }
  },
  source: function(request, response) {
    ...
  }
});
```